# Obfuscating the python interpreter

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, obfuscation, interpreter

I am creating a python app which I am packaging using py2app. I am also trying to obfuscate the pyc the way dropbox has done ie. by scrambling the opcodes in include\opcode.h. I am trying to install the new python using the following commands:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

However, when I run the second command (make), I get a segmentation fault:

```
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: libpython3.4m.a(dynamic_annotations.o) has no symbols
/opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: libpython3.4m.a(pymath.o) has no symbols
ranlib libpython3.4m.a
ranlib: file: libpython3.4m.a(dynamic_annotations.o) has no symbols
ranlib: file: libpython3.4m.a(pymath.o) has no symbols
CoreFoundation     
CoreFoundation     
./python.exe -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
make: *** [pybuilddir.txt] Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have also tried making the corresponding changes to lib/opcode.py but I am still getting the seg fault. What am I doing wrong?